# jedi-vim auto completion after first letter

Tags: autocomplete, jedi-vim

Is there a way to make jedi-vim automatically start the completion after typing any letter without pressing < C-Space >?
Is it maybe possible to bind

let g:jedi#completions_command = "< C-Space >"

command to every single letter while keeping their typing function?
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not yet. Something like this is planned, but we will need a proper async server first.

You could of course hack something together, but that would be painstakingly slow. So don't.

If you really want that, go and `YouCompleteMe` for now: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe. It's using Jedi as well for Python, so it's pretty much the same.

Comment: I just tried YCM and it works nicely even tho I would prefer the jedi-vim. Hope it gets implemented soon.